# How to test resetForm function for template driven forms in angular using Jasmine Karm test?

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine, angular-forms, angular-unit-test

I am trying to unit test resetform() function [used as TemplateVar.resetForm()] where **loginVar** is used as template variable for template driven form in angular.
I am not getting any sources oridea ho to do that. Please guide. Thanks in advance!

**component.html**

````
<form #loginVar="ngForm">
```code form fields```
</form>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onReset(loginVar)">Reset</button>
````

**component.ts**

```
  onReset(e) {
    e.resetForm();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  it('should reset form', () => {
    const debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    const form: NgForm = debugElement.children[0].injector.get(NgForm);
    const spy = spyOn(form, 'resetForm');
    component.ClearForm(form);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

This worked!